# To what extent were Jack McCoy's closing arguments ad-libbed?

Tags: acting, law-and-order

Many episodes of *Law & Order* culminate with a passionate closing argument delivered by Jack McCoy.

Often, these aren't merely dramatic speeches, nor are they just doing the work of advancing the plot (i.e. to get us to the jury verdict where fates are revealed). Rather, this is when the episode's philosophical concerns crystallize. It's when the show writers present *to the audience* what seems to be their best arguments.

So, if we consider L&O as a kind of real-world public dialogue on our society's pursuit of justice, McCoy's closing arguments are where that dialogue is usually the least-disguised. So I assume that the writers would want actor Sam Waterston to stay as close as possible to the exact text of the script.

But some of those closing arguments are pretty long. I know actors are in the business of memorizing lines, and none of these speeches set any records for length, but I still wonder.

Is there any info about whether Sam did any ad-libbing?

Comment: "But some of those closing arguments are pretty long." So? These are not minute-long single takes. Plenty of actors can retain long swathes of text. There are plays that last more than two hours and they need to know all their lines for those as well.

Comment: Script supervisors [used to be called continuity] & editors don't like ad-libs. They make cutting a scene together much harder if takes are not similar. [Also, background may not react properly if the dialog wanders off from the script] Fine for movies when your edit may take 6 months, but not for TV when you might only have a week.

Comment: I once saw a script supervisor have "a word" with an A-lister who had swapped one word in a 7 page monologue which he'd already got right maybe 8 or 10 times in a row. He'd swapped "that" for "it" or something equally trivial. I thought that was just a tad *too keen*.

Comment: In live theater they don't have editing... they remember all their lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start by saying, there is zero probability you will get a direct answer unless you can find an interview with Waterson where he is asked this question.  And, given it's implausible, I'll bet my bottom dollar it's not what an interviewer wants to know.

That being said, the concept of Soliloquys have been inherent in theater since the early days of performance.  Memorizing lengthy dialogue and scenes have always been a part of theater.  So, just the simple thought of him memorizing a lengthy speech is pretty much part of the job of an actor.  However, also remember that every single camera cut, from angle to angle, has the potential to be a stoppage of action.  In between, at worst, an actor can refresh his memory of lines to be delivered until the next cut.  But, if you're a professional actor and you've done theater (which Waterson has), you probably want to take pride in memorizing your lines.

Comment: Yup. I've seen people memorise 10-15 minute scenes overnight. If you saw the recent show 'Landscapers', the court scenes were shot top to bottom every single time [though later inter-cut]. Whilst David Thewlis was delivering his 'day in court', Olivia Coleman had her script for tomorrow on her lap, out of shot, which she was learning between takes. I once saw Tom Wilkinson deliver the closing legal statement in Belle top to bottom for an entire day. Then they changed the script & he was back again the next day having memorised the new [totally different] version. The pros really can just do it

Comment: See also: Ian McShane having to learn lengthy soliloquies that David Milch wrote for his character in Deadwood mere hours before they were filming the scene.